# Google Maps API v3 - Marker shadow disappears

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Here's the basic code, I cut it straight out:

```
      var loadposition = new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$feed['location'][0]?>,<?=$feed['location'][1]?>);
      var markerSize = new google.maps.Size(20,34);
      var houseMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage("marker2.png",markerSize);

      var markerShadowSize = new google.maps.Size(30,34);
      var markerShadowPoint = new google.maps.Point(30,0);
      var markerShadowAnchor = new google.maps.Point(0,35);
      var houseMarkerShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("marker2.png",markerShadowSize,markerShadowPoint,markerShadowAnchor);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:loadposition,
            title:"<?=$feed['name']?>",
            draggable:false,
            clickable:true,
            icon:houseMarker,
            shadow:houseMarkerShadow
        });

        marker.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e){
            var loadposition = new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$feed['location'][0]?>,<?=$feed['location'][1]?>);
            var htmlContent = "<?=$feed['name']?><br/><?=$feed['address']?>";

            infowindow.setPosition( loadposition );
            infowindow.setContent(htmlContent);
            infowindow.open(map);
        });
```

For some reason, the shadow does not show.  However, If I enable drag and drop and/or set up a marker animation (either bounce or drop) the shadow shows up once it's lifted up..  But as soon as the marker lays down the shadow disappears.

I can not find any other documentation on this nor similar questions / answers.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that the syntax is correct.  It's actually a bug with Google Chrome and Safari.  Internet explorer and Firefox all render the shadow correctly.

The bug is opened at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3993

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, it was an actual bug at the time of the post... https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3993

Answer (score 0):

The shadow image needs to be different than the marker image.

For example the marker shadow for google maps is like this;
http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png

From your code;

```
var houseMarkerShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("marker2.png",markerShadowSize,markerShadowPoint,markerShadowAnchor);
```

Having the same image marker2.png as both the marker and the shadow probably isn't going to work as you expect.

Comment: It's not that, the syntax is correct.  In fact, I've determined the issue is only in Google Chrome / Safari.  It's a rendering issue.  The case is opened with Google.

Comment: It may have been helpful to link the problem on your website to start with.
Also I can't see where you set "var marker".

The example that Google has set http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex.html works fine for me in all browsers, you need to take a better look at your code.

Comment: var marker is declared at line 618; which is executed first before function init().